# how to load dump on docker mysql container based on centos6?

Tags: docker, mysql

I am trying to create my own mysql docker container based on official centos6 image. I am successful in building and running mysql container. However, i would like to have dump loaded when container starts. Now this is generating error:

"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' "

Please help.

I have following configuration loading when building image:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Borrowed from https://github.com/docker-library/docker-mysql

set -e

if [ -z "$(ls -A /var/lib/mysql)" -a -n "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
        if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
                echo >&2 'error: database is uninitialized and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD not set'
                echo >&2 '  Did you forget to add -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=... ?'
                exit 1
        fi

        scl enable mysql55 "mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql"

        # These statements _must_ be on individual lines, and _must_ end with
        # semicolons (no line breaks or comments are permitted).
        # TODO proper SQL escaping on dat root password D:
        cat > /tmp/mysql-first-time.sql <<-EOSQL
                DELETE FROM mysql.user ;
                CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
                GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
                CREATE USER 'mysql'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
                GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON *.* TO 'mysql'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
                CREATE USER ''@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
                GRANT ALL ON *.* TO ''@'%' IDENTIFIED BY IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
                DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test ;
                commit;
                FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
        EOSQL

        scl enable mysql55 "mysqld_safe --init-file=/tmp/mysql-first-time.sql &"
        sleep 5
        exec scl enable mysql55 "mysqladmin -uroot -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} shutdown"
fi

chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
exec scl enable mysql55 "mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create an unnamed user in these lines:

`CREATE USER ''@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;
                GRANT ALL ON *.* TO ''@'%' IDENTIFIED BY IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}' ;`

I don't know if that's valid in your SQL engine, but I don't think it is legal in MySQL.